# Reading CSV column values and append to List in Python

Tags: python-3.x, list, read.csv

I'd like to read a column from a CSV file and store those values in a list

The CSV file is currently as below

| Names |
| --- |
| Tom |
| Ryan |
| John |

---

#### The result that I'm looking for is

`['Tom', 'Ryan', 'John']`

#### Below is the code that I've written.

---

```
import csv
import pandas as pd
import time


# Declarations
UserNames = []

# Open a csv file using pandas

data_frame = pd.read_csv("analysts.csv", header=1, index_col=False)
names = data_frame.to_string(index=False)
# print(names)

# Iteration
for name in names:
    UserNames.append(name)
print(UserNames)
```

---

#### So far the result is as follows

`['T', 'o', 'm', ' ', '\n', 'R', 'y', 'a', 'n', '\n', 'J', 'o', 'h', 'n']`

---

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: For what reason are you using a pandas data frame and why are converting it to a string?

Comment: is the CSV just a singe column of names or are there other columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi instead of using converting your Dataframe to a String you could just convert it to a list like this:

```
import pandas as pd 
import csv 
import time 

df = pd.read_csv("analyst.csv", header=0)
names = df["Name"].to_list()
print(names)
```

Output: ['tom', 'tim', 'bob']

Csv File:

```
Name,
tom,
tim,
bob,
```

I was not sure how your csv really looked like so you could have to adjust the arguments of the `read_csv` function.